# Many network adapters at machine, need to find one that is used for traffic in Windows (from .net)

Tags: .net, network-programming, mac-address

My application use Web-service. I'm control from what workstation was request and for this send MAC-Address how parameter of all methods. But then I start testing application in real, I found workstations which have many network adapters - Ethernet, Wireless, Bluetooth. When I get MAC-address using next code:

```
var networkAdapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
if (networkAdapters == null || networkAdapters.Length == 0)
    return string.Empty;

string address = string.Empty;

foreach (var adapter in networkAdapters)
{
    var a = adapter.GetPhysicalAddress();
    if (a != null && a.ToString() != string.Empty)
    {
        address = a.ToString();
        break;
    }
}
return address;
```

Sometimes Web-service receive from workstation different MAC-Addresses, but I want get always only one MAC-address. Please, help me.

Comment: We're really getting to the crux of the problem here - that MAC address is *not* a singleton anymore - multiple NICs is a regular phenomenon.  You need an alternate system for licence than MAC e.g. a workstation key or certificate.

Answer (score 0):

If I had two different ethernet cards - two different MAC addresses - which MAC address would be the right address?

Answering that is the root of answering this question. You have to create the algorithm to pick the right choice - there are lots of tools at hand to enable you to be more discriminating:

1. [`GetIsNetworkAvailable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable.aspx)`==true` - identifies only interfaces with active connections
2. [`Speed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.speed.aspx) - enables you to probe for fastest connection
3. [`NetworkInterfaceType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.networkinterfacetype.aspx) e.g. Ethernet

Even given these rules, multiple adapters may still match.  e.g. a machine with multiple NICs bound to the same LAN. Only you can determine rules for tiebreakers.

Comment: OK, for your best understand - I'm using MAC-address for security check, system licensing on count clients. On web-service side in database write list MAC-addresses which can connect to service, and one machine must be identify by one MAC-address, but de facto MAC-address from machines with many network adapters received on service side may be different, what create problem for me.

Comment: Two thoughts, MAC address is user spoofable - while it will prevent concurrent use (two NICs cant have same MAC, it won't prevent MAC address reuse).  You're still caught by having multiple legitimate paths e.g. Wireless and Ethernet adapters on a laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You know what IP address your application is using for the Web service, right? Precisely one adapter will have this IP address.

Ypou can check this via `GetIPProperties` > `UnicastAddresses`

Comment: If MAC address is the licence count, and I have laptop that has a)  Ethernet NIC in a docking station, and b) wireless NIC, it can conceivably be in four states - no MACs, MAC a, MAC b, or MAC a + MAC b.  What would my licence use for my laptop be?

Comment: When connecting via Ethernet, MAC a. When connecting via Wifi, MAC b. The first state (no MAC) means you're not connected at all, so license counts are irrelevant.

Comment: OP is using MAC address to allocate licences - so our laptop would need to be registered for both MAC addresses. OPs current system doesn't support that - he (incorrectly) assumed that all PCs would have a single MAC address.